# Compare observed distribution of values vs bootstrapped values

Tags: distributions, bootstrap

To prove the efficacy of a test (to be more precise, a moderated t-test from two groups of samples), I need to compare the p-values obtained from my test against a null distribution of 1000 random p-values generated by permutation (rationale: show that Type I errors are accounted for properly).

My goal is to determine whether the observed values from the test differ significantly from the null distribution I generated.

What would be the best approach (pointers to R or Python packages would be appreciated, if possible)?

Comment: Apart from the effect of discreteness, under the null, both sets of p-values should be uniform, shouldn't they? As for comparing their distribution, if you want a hypothesis test, there are a number of goodness of fit tests, but at sufficient sample size they'll reject any difference, even if it's not practically important. It may be better to identify the effect size (the size of the difference in cdf, say, near commonly used significance levels) in order to demonstrate their closeness.